# mysql - Max occurences of a given value in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id    | cid   | grade |g_point|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |
| 2     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |
| 3     |  10   |  B    |   3   |
| 4     |  11   |  A    |   2   |
| 5     |  11   |  A+   |   1   |
| 6     |  12   |  B    |   3   |
```

the column `g_point` is the values associated to each grade. forexample A+ grade considers highest so I assign the value of A+ is one(highest starts from 1 to 10) and so on. These `g_point` values are constant. Now what I want to do is I want to show the maximum grade against each course and also if somehow there are only two entries of different grades I want to compare it with the **g_point** and choose whose value is lower because lower integer value means higher grade. the result should be like this and also sorted from top grade to lower.

```
+-------+-------+
| cid   | grade |
+-------+-------+
| 10    |   A+  |
| 11    |   A+  |
| 12    |   B   |
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT coursecodeID AS cid, (SELECT grade 
                             FROM feedback 
                             WHERE coursecodeID = cid 
                             GROUP BY grade 
                             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS g 
FROM feedback 
GROUP BY coursecodeID
```

but in this query I don't know how can I compare it with g_point value and also the courses is not showing in order(from highest grade to lowest).

NOTE: I want to choose the grade having the maximum number of occurrences per course id. For example here in this table course id 10 has 2 A+ grade so we'll consider A+ and if clash happens like one is A+ and the other is B+, then we'll have to compare it with the g_point

Comment: Come on. Try something. Also, not much point storing grade. Just store g_point

Comment: I have already tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.cid, m1.grade
FROM mytable AS m1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT cid, MIN(g_point) AS maxGrade
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY cid ) m2
ON m1.cid = m2.cid AND m1.g_point = m2.maxGrade
```

The derived table contains the minimum `g_point` per `cid`. If you join it back to the original table, then you can get the maximum grade per `cid`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc6f4/1)

**EDIT:**

You can alternatively use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT cid, (SELECT grade
             FROM mytable AS m2
             WHERE m2.cid = m1.cid 
             ORDER BY g_point LIMIT 1) AS maxGrade     
FROM mytable AS m1
GROUP BY cid
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc6f4/2)

**EDIT2:**

It looks like you want to get the grade having the *maximum number of occurrences* per `cid`. In case there are more than one grades sharing this maximum number, then fetch the grade with the lowest `g_point`.

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT cid, grade 
FROM (
  SELECT cid, grade,
         @row_number := IF (@cid <> cid,
                           IF (@cid := cid, 1, 1),
                           IF (@cid := cid, @row_number+1, @row_number+1)) AS rn
  FROM (                         
    SELECT cid, grade, 
           COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
           (SELECT g_point 
            FROM mytable AS m2
            WHERE m1.grade = m2.grade 
            LIMIT 1) AS g_point
    FROM mytable AS m1
    GROUP BY cid, grade 
  ) t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number:=-1, @cid:=-1) AS vars
  ORDER BY cid, cnt DESC, g_point
) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9ce0/1)

Comment: hello Thanks for your answer. see I have edited some values. you can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2368f

I am not getting correct result. the result should be B+ but I am getting an A+

Comment: @hellosheikh All records in your fiddle have the **same** `cid` value. `A+` is the highest grade and it is returned correctly by my query.

Comment: yes it all has the same value. you can see four courses(cid) has B+ grade, three has A+ and one has A. so I need the max so shouldn't the grade be B+ ?

Comment: Okay Okay let me explain you. the comparing only occurs at that time when there is a clash. otherwise grade will be chosen on the maximum occurrence. For example if two has received A and other two has received B now there is a clash so grade would be consider as A not B because of its lowest value

Comment: @hellosheikh Have a look at the data in your fiddle: there is *only one* course there.

Comment: @hellosheikh So? There is only one course: `cid = 10`. Pick the highest grade: `A+`. Is there any error here?

Comment: yes. because we have to pick the highest grade based on the maximum occurrence. B+ is occuring four times so it should print out B+ ? can we chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82897/discussion-between-hellosheikh-and-giorgos-betsos).

Comment: @hellosheikh So, *we have to pick the highest grade based on the maximum occurrence*. Where exactly in your question do you make that clear?

Comment: Yes exactly I am really sorry if that was not clear. Let me edit my question too

Answer (score 0):

This works, but needs the 'g_point' to alse be returned.

```
SELECT cid,grade,MIN(g_point)
FROM grades
GROUP BY cid
```

This is more reliable, as it generates the Grade in the sub-query, and then appends it to the main table.

```
SELECT cid, (
    SELECT grade
    FROM grades g2
    WHERE g2.cid = g1.cid 
    ORDER BY g_point
    LIMIT 1
) AS grade     
FROM grades g1
GROUP BY cid
```

Comment: `grade` returned by this query is *not* guaranteed to be related to the row having the `MIN(g_point)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT i 
     , CONCAT(CHAR((i/2)+64),IF(MOD(i,2)=1,'+',''))n 
  FROM ints 
 WHERE i > 0;
+---+------+
| i | n    |
+---+------+
| 1 | A+   |
| 2 | A    |
| 3 | B+   |
| 4 | B    |
| 5 | C+   |
| 6 | C    |
| 7 | D+   |
| 8 | D    |
| 9 | E+   |
+---+------+
```